# set-theoretic difference of multisets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the result of $A \backslash B$ , if $A$ and $B$ are multisets?

For instance, if $A = \{1,1,3\}$ and $B = \{1,2\}$, would the result of $A \backslash B$ be $\{1,3\}$ or $\{3\}$?

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question and I'm not sure that there is a universally agreed upon definition of set theoretic difference for multisets. In the theoretical computer courses that I took, we used the following formalization of multisets:

A multiset $X$ is a function
$$
X \colon \mathrm{dom}(X) \to \mathbb N^+.
$$
$x$ is an element of $X$ iff $x \in \mathrm{dom}(X)$. $X(x)$ is the multiplicity of $x$ in the multiset $X$.

Note that a multiset is uniquely determined by its elements and their multiplicity.

Given two multisets $X,Y$ we can define a multiset
$$
X \cap Y \colon \mathrm{dom}(X) \cap \mathrm{dom}(Y) \to \mathbb N^+, z \mapsto \min\{X(z),Y(z) \}
$$
and likewise
$$
X \cup Y \colon \mathrm{dom}(X) \cup \mathrm{dom}(Y) \to \mathbb N^+, z \mapsto X(z) + Y(z),
$$
where we let $X(z) := 0$ for $z \not \in \mathrm{dom}(X)$ and likewise for $Y$.

We also define
$$
X \setminus Y \colon \{ x \in \mathrm{dom}(X) \mid x \not \in \mathrm{dom}(Y) \vee (x \in \mathrm{dom}(Y) \wedge X(x) > Y(x) \} \to \mathbb N, z \mapsto X(z)- Y(z).
$$

We may write (at least finite) multisets in the fashion that you did. And doing so this definition would yield that
$$
\{1,1,3\} \setminus \{1,2\} = \{1,3 \} \text{ and } \{1,1,3\} \setminus \{1,1,2 \} = \{3\}.
$$

Comment: It's sometimes convenient to allow for infinite multiplicities in multisets (and here I mean infinite in the naive sense). For example, we used to write $\{1^*\}$ for the multiset that has $1$ as its unique member and an infinite multiplicity for $1$. The main point of this definition is that we then know that $1 \not \in X \setminus \{1^*\}$ for any multiset $X$.

Comment: The multiset union of X - Y and X$\cap$Y does not give X.  Instead of union, sum needs be used.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Multiset union is defined via sums: $X \cup Y \colon \mathrm{dom}(X) \cup \mathrm{dom}(Y), z \mapsto X(z) + Y(z)$, where $X(z) := 0$ if $z \not \in \mathrm{dom}(X)$ and likewise for $Y$. And then $(X \setminus Y) \cup (X \cap Y) = X$. So... yeah... I'm not sure what you are hinting at with your comment.

Comment: Similar for union would mean using the maximum.  But now you are using sum.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I thought it was pretty obvious how multiset union should be defined. That's why I didn't spell it out. But, yes, I had the definition in mind that I provided in my comment above. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: See Wikipedia that definds union with maximum and sum with sum.  Sum is not similar to minimum;  maximum is.

Answer (score 0):

Let K = A - B.  Then A = K $\cup (A\cap B).$
Thus for multisets, you want a K with
A = K multiunion (A multiintersection B).
For A = {1,1,3}, B = {1,2}, A multiintersection B = {1}.
So K = {1,1,3} since {1,1,3} multiunion {1} = {1,1,3}.

More intuitive would be to look for a K with
A = K sum (A multiintersection B).  That would be
K = {1,3} since {1,3} sum {1} = {1,1,3}.

See Wikipedia for definitions.